# Symfony Http Client default headers not added

Tags: symfony, http

I'm using the Http Client to send a request to an external API. According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/http_client.html#scoping-client) I can add default headers to a specific route like so:

```
framework:
  http_client:
    scoped_clients:
      the_api:
        base_uri: '%env(the_url)%'
        headers:
          Authorization: 'Bearer %env(my_token)%'
```

That doesn't work for me. I also tried this option:

```
auth_bearer: '%env(my_token)%'
```

same effect.

In the service I use to make the request I have:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $theUrl, [
    'body' => $dataArray
]);
```

With the above configuration I get a 403 response, as if the token is not sent. If I add it to the `request()` function however it works:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $theUrl, [
    'body' => $dataArray,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $myToken
    ]
]);
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid fetching the token in my service or controller. In the future I might send other requests to the API (or a different API) and I don't want to set the token for each one.

If it matters `$theUrl` is https.
Symfony and Http Client versions: 4.4

Comment: you may have overread this part, since you didn't mention it all: "If you use scoped clients in the Symfony framework, you must use any of the methods defined by Symfony to [choose a specific service](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html#services-wire-specific-service)." (source: your reference)

Comment: @Jakumi you pointed me to something that works. I added the token as an argument when registering a service (I did't register it before). However instead of a service I changed it to a component which extends an abstract base class. If I have to make the same type of request to a different API will create another similar component. This works because different APIs might require different arguments. Thanks. PS I'm still adding it in the `request()` function but with this config it is ok, I removed the scoped clients.

Answer (score 11):

You must use the client name `the_api` in your case.

```
#config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    http_client:
        scoped_clients:
            name_client:
                base_uri: 'http://ip:port/'
                auth_basic: 'user:password'
```

client name here `name_client`

```
#src/Controller/MyController.php
...
public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $name_client)
{
    $this->client = $name_client;
}
...
```

`$name_client` will contain an instance of the `ScopingHttpClient` class with the specified parameters

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my scoped client doesn't add default authorization header. My solution was to inject the token in my service and initialize a brand new flat `HttpClient` object like this:

```
$client = \Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient::create(['headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $this->token,
    ]]);
```